# Should we combine or totally separate the tags [salt] and [seasoning]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

These two tags are somewhat redundant as written:

[salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salt):

> Questions about the use of culinary salt in the kitchen.

[seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning):

> Questions about the use of salt, spices and other flavorings to create the desired flavor in the final dish.

I propose two options for the community to consider:

1. Combine the two. "Seasoning" is very often used to refer to salt, particularly by chefs. When they say "underseasoned", they usually mean "lacking salt".
2. Remove "salt" from the [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning) tag and only use it to refer to herbs and spices and other flavorings. We have a tag for salt specifically, there's no reason to double tag something.

What are your thoughts on this?

I noticed this in the edit suggestion for [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66450/should-i-add-salt-when-boiling-vegetable-why), where a user recommended adding both tags, which I felt was redundant, particularly since the question has nothing to do with seasoning, and everything to do with salt, so I only added the [salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salt) tag.

Answer (score 9):

Since the answer below was well-received, I updated the tag wiki for [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning) as described below, and the tags will stay separate.

---

Of the two, I definitely favor the second. The first doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me: we'd have to merge [salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salt) into [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning), and then everyone who *doesn't* equate "seasoning" and "salt" would be confused.

So maybe just a slight tweak to [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning):

> Questions about the use of spices, herbs, salt and other flavorings to create the desired flavor in the final dish. See also [salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salt).

That said, I'm not sure how worried I am about it. Trying to keep tags from overlapping is a good general goal but I'm not sure how possible it is in practice. We have [baking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking) along with [cookies](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies), [cake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cake), and so on. So it seems just as acceptable for [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning) and [salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salt) to coexist. It seems fair to use [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning) when you're asking about something more general (possibly including salt!), and use [salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salt) when you care specifically about salt.

Comment: Sure, that makes total sense... perhaps if we de-emphasize "salt" from the "seasoning" tag? Rather than have it be the first seasoning listed, list it later to emphasize the flavoring elements?

Comment: That being said, I don't know that "cookies" and "baking" are exactly analogous.

Comment: @Catija The analogy was mostly about current tag definitions, where we're treating seasoning as a general thing which includes salt. (I know the "some people think they're synonyms part" doesn't carry over though.)

Comment: This works for me. To me salt is **a** seasoning, but not the only one. I know that some consider salt to be synonymous with seasoning, but not everyone sees it that way.

Comment: Just a thought: I think we cannot lose the "salt" tag completely as you can use salt for other uses than just seasoning (e.g., in a crust).

Answer (score 1):

Salt is often used as a preservative, not a spice.

Matias style herrings are simply inedible without further processing (either washing them, or adding to some sauce/dish that is not pre-salted, so their saltiness is diluted, while seasoning the dish) - using 'seasoning' in case of preserving foods with salt would be quite counter-intuitive.